# browser/window event for deleting/managing cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

In the browser, is there an event on window that you can listen to for managing cookies? Something like:

```
window.addEventListener('deletecookie', function(event){

});
```

how can we know on the front-end if cookies have changed?

Comment: All I see is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies

Comment: no dude, I want to listen for events in the browser, using JavaScript running in the browser, this doesn't really have to do with selenium, maybe I should untag selenium...

Comment: In raw JavaScript you can check if cookies are changed with [**cookies.onChanged**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged).